# What is the size of special characters for facettes?

Tags: xsd

How are handle the special characters for length related facettes in an xml schema ? Are they one character, or the number with special form ?

For instance, is `<` (`&lt;`) one character, or four characters ?

if it is four characters, how is it possible to say to the users something like *Excuse me, if you type `<` it's four characters* ?

Thanks.

Comment: I find an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976385/does-amp-count-as-one-or-multiple-chars-in-an-xml-file !

Answer (score 0):

The XML escapes are handled prior to schema validation.  So, if the XML has:

```
<myelement>4 &lt; 5</myelement>
```

Then the myelement content is "4 < 5", which is 4 characters.